# Package to be used for `question` environment

Tags: exam

I am working in document class `book`. I want to add exercises in each section of each chapter. My following code (I am sharing only part of cde due to which I am getting an error) is not getting compiled. Perhaps I am not using required package, which package should I use?

Also, I want to give numbering to my questions 1, 2, 3 and so on throughout the chapter. Means, numbering should not go section-wise.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Def{i}nition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Quadratic Equation}
\section{Problems}
\begin{questions}
\question \quad Let \(\alpha,\ \beta \) be the roots of the equation \(x^2 - px + r = 0\) and \     (\dfrac{\alpha}{2},\ 2\beta\) be the roots of the equation \(x^2 - qx + r = 0\). Then the value of the \        (r\) is

    \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice \(\dfrac{2}{9}(p-q)(2q - p)\) 
    \choice \(\dfrac{2}{9}(q - p)(2p - q)\) 
    \choice \(\dfrac{2}{9}(q - 2p)(2q - p)\) 
    \choice \(\dfrac{2}{9}(2p - q)(2q - p)\)
    \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `questions` and `oneparchoices` environments are part of the `exam` documentclass. You cannot use them with another documentclass, such as `book`. There are other possibilities, for example the `xsim` package provides multiple choice questions (see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/xsim_manual.pdf#page=60).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility, based on `enumitem` and `tasks`: I defined a `questions` enumerated list, with *ad hoc* parameters. To ensure a continuous numbering throughout the chapter, from the second list on, until the end of the chapter, you just have to load the environment with the key `[resume]`.

Next, I defined a `oneparchoices` environment with the `\NewTask` command, from the `tasks` package. By default, I set it to 4 columns, but it can be changed on calling the environment (last argument, between parentheses).

```
\documentclass{book}}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Def{i}nition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[questions]{label=\arabic*., wide=0pt, font=\bfseries}
\let\question=\item
\usepackage{tasks}
\NewTasks[label=$\square$,after-item-skip=0ex plus 1ex]{oneparchoices}[\choice](4)
\let\choice=\task

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Quadratic Equation}

\section{Problems}
\begin{questions}
\question Let \(\alpha,\ \beta \) be the roots of the equation \(x^2 - px + r = 0\) and \(\mfrac{\alpha}{2},\ 2\beta\) be the roots of the equation \(x^2 - qx + r = 0\). Then the value of the \(r\) is

 \begin{oneparchoices}(3)
 \choice \(\mfrac{2}{9}(p-q)(2q - p)\)

 \choice \(\mfrac{2}{9}(q - p)(2p - q)\)

 \choice \(\mfrac{2}{9}(q - 2p)(2q - p)\)

 \choice \(\mfrac{2}{9}(2p - q)(2q - p)\)
 \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]